# How do I set up an Electrolyzer to make electrolytic water cells?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit, minecraft-industrialcraft

In tekkit, I need to set up an electrolyzer so I can get my centrifuge Extractor. I have the current setup (Top view)

```
                   [ ]  <- MFE
                    |_______[LVT]____>Machines
                    |
                   [E]  <-Electrolyzer
```

When I add water cells to the electrolyzer, it does not charge. Ideas/Fixes? Everything is linked up via glass fiber cables. LVT is low voltage transformer (found this after blowing a few rotary macerators up, and I play survival, so ouch.)

Comment: forgot to mention, MFE Is charged up way to 600000/600000 Electrical units. (EU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electrolyzers, unlike other machines, need to be directly adjacent to a power source (MFE or MFSU). They can be against any side of said source I believe, but must share a side with it rather than be connected via wiring.

The solution is to just place your electrolyzer next to your MFE, leaving the normal output face of your MFE open to run cabling to your LV transformer and other machines.

Additional info: [industrialcraft wiki](http://wiki.industrial-craft.net/index.php?title=Electrolyzer)

To explain why this is, it appears part of the function of the electrolyzer is also to recharge the MFE or MFSU. This gives you a way to store excess power at the cost of some efficiency, but with the benefit of being able to move it later (in the form of the electrolyzed water cells).

Comment: nice. worked beautifully.

Comment: I noticed it also only works when the MFE/MFSU has 70% or more power. is this a bug?

Comment: I believe that's the intended behavior. This is to support the recharging function -- since the MFE charges the electrolyzer and the electrolyzer charges the MFE, there are various breakpoints at which various functions turn on or off to try and balance the charges. The linked wiki lists a couple of these breakpoints. The tekkit wiki entry also has similar information: http://thetekkit.wikia.com/wiki/Electrolyzer